Can a part of the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem be proven using only first order logic?
Can a part of the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem be proven using only first order logic? I ask because of the following:

Let SM be the predicate set of mathematical structures
Let CA be the predicate cardinal number
Let MA be the predicate member of A
Let EB be the predicate equals B
∃A∃B∃C(SM(A)∧CA(B)∧MA(C)∧EB(C)) translates to, there are some A, B, and C such that A is a set of mathematical structures, B is a cardinal number, C is a member of A, and C equals B.
∀A∀B∃C(SM(A)∧CA(B)→MA(C)∧EB(C)) translates to, for all A and B there exists C such that if A is a set of mathematical structures and B is a cardinal number, then C is a member of A and C equals B.
∃A∃B∃C(SM(A)∧CA(B)∧MA(C)∧EB(C))→∀A∀B∃C(SM(A)∧CA(B)→MA(C)∧EB(C)) is a validity in first order logic.
I would be tempted to use Modus Ponens on (7) since ∃A∃B∃C(SM(A)∧CA(B)∧MA(C)∧EB(C)) seems true


It may be more appropriate to ask about this on the math stack exchange site.

How are you going to prove a theorem whose formulation involves higher order concepts (like structures) in first-order logic that does not include them?

@Conifold, isn’t a structure a set though?

Not exactly. It is a set together with a map that interprets formal language on it, a.k.a. extensional interpretation. In other words, a meta-object. First-order languages do not have means to reference themselves and express such meta-objects.

@Conifold but a structure is still a set though.

Not in the sense you want to use it for.

Wait, when you said set, do you mean set in first order logic or second order logic?

@conifold, is that the only definition of mathematical structure? Because another way to define mathematical structure is as a group. And a group can either be interpreted as a set in first order logic or second order logic.

@Conifold: The OP implicitly uses the following definition of structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure?wprov=sfti1#

Wikipedia typically does not give definitions, just some vague gist, and even that is not too reliable. And, in any case, you need to link structures as sets with relations to language expressions to even formulate  Löwenheim–Skolem, as even Wikipedia dutifully reports in the corresponding article.
